# Binary View in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the below data that shows the frequency of customer credit transactions, but I actually want it to show a binary view so if a customer has received a credit I want it to show 1 instead of the actual number of credits and if the customer hasn't received credits then it should show a 0.

This is how it looks:

```
     ID  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep
   123    8    8    7    0    5   0
   456    0    1    2    0    4    2
   789    3    0    0    0    0    2
```

This is what i want it to look like:

```
    ID   Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep
   123    1    1    1    0    1   0
   456    0    1    1    0    1    1
   789    1    0    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
df = (df > 0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Nice - this is very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in a Pandas Dataframe and only with the months' columns, here's something that can work:

```
for cols in df.columns:
    df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >0 else 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShreyasG,highly appreciated